# In django 4.1, with debug=True, in admin, I can upload images but can't display it

Tags: debugging, django-admin

In Django 4.1 admin I'm having a problem: i can upload files but can't show it.

My environment is:

running the development server with: **python manage.py runserver --insecure 0.0.0.0:8000**

The project root is in **C:\django\humm\humm**

The project tree is:

```
- humm
    - backend
        ...
        admin.py
        models.py
        ...
    - humm
        ...
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
    - media
        - images
            pd.png (successfully uploaded image)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**models.py:**

```
...
class Produto(models.Model):
    ...
    descricao = models.CharField(db_column='product_name', max_length=40)
    imagem_pequena = models.ImageField(db_column='small_image', upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
...
class ProdutoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def thumb_pequeno(self, obj):
        if obj.imagem_pequena:
            return format_html('<img src="{}" style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px"/>', obj.imagem_pequena.url)
        else:
            return '-'
    thumb_pequeno.short_description = 'pequena'

    # i tried 'imagem_pequena.allow_tags = True, but this was deprecated in 
    # Django 4.11 in favor of format_html'

    readonly_fields = [...,'thumb_pequeno',]
    list_display = ['descricao','thumb_pequeno',]
...
admin.site.register(Produto, ProdutoAdmin)
```

**settings.py:**

```
...
DEBUG = True   # in shell it was confimed as true
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'backend'
]
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'humm.urls'
...
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    # BASE_DIR in shell give: WindowsPath('C:/django/humm/humm')
 ...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
    # STATIC_ROOT in shell give: WindowsPath('C:/django/humm/humm/static')
...
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
    # MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    # both ways, in shell MEDIA_ROOT give: 'C:\\django\\humm\\humm\\media'
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

What can I do to show the uploaded images in admin interface ?

Comment: Error: imagem_pequena.allow_tags => thumb_pequeno.allow_tags

And i forgot to mention that the image not found message:
Not Found: /media/images/pd.png
[20/Mar/2023 10:50:04] "GET /media/images/pd.png HTTP/1.1" 404 5737
, and when I try with the broser: http://localhost:8000//media/images/pd.png
I get a Page not found.

Comment: The differences in shell display format between MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT was because a shell bed command to load the settings, now both show the WindowsPath().

Comment: Commenting the urls.py line 'urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)' make no difference.

Comment: Tried without success the answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177385/visualizing-uploaded-images-in-django-admin?rq=1

Comment: Also, the html code is (i added the 'href'): <img href="/media/images/pd.png" src="/media/images/pd.png" style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px">